# My fixed navbar doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css, menu, fixed, navbar

I made a fixed navbar, but when I scroll you see the navbar behind the other images. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is a link with the navbar (it supposed to fit in the white bar but in Dreamweaver it all looks good).

So I want the fixed navbar that scrolls over all the divs. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: You should provide the code in here for us to see. But it sounds like you need to put `z-index: 999;` on the `nav`.

Comment: Good stuff! Glad we could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use in your CSS the z-index property?

Like so:

```
z-index:999;
```

Comment: The `z-index` property is much more complex than that. Giving an abstractly high number may not change anything.

Comment: Is this an answer or question?... "You should use the `z-index` property" if its an answer. If its a question don't make an answer :D

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Without the code its hard to tell what they need so I guess we will have to wait and see. (That's why I put mine as a comment) but this could be correct.

Comment: Its an implicited answer... I'm asking him to try it because that would work.

Comment: He wouldn't show the link but here it is! http://jsfiddle.net/2y3UX/
I know the menu doesn't look good, but in dreamweaver the text fits in the menu.

Comment: As I said try to use inside your #navbar{ z-index:999;} If my answer worked for you please give it a check :)